# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id' in azure mobile server

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

This is my code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server;
public class MessageController : TableController<Message> 
{
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMessage(Message item) 
  {
    Message current;
    try
    {
      current = await InsertAsync(item);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      throw; //  Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id'
    }
    return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
  }
}
```

it gives me : Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id'

the strange thing is that the Id is Generated and it is assigned to item.Id but still an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that in the migration process somehow the Id column default value is not set to (newid()).

just set it manually.
the same thing for CreatedAt column should be set to (sysutcdatetime())